# How to inject custom SSL certs into springbok bootBuildImage

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, gradle

I'm not sure if this is possible w/out making a custom base image to use but I'm trying to build images behind a corporate firewall with self-signed SSL certs:

```
> Task :bootBuildImage
Caching disabled for task ':bootBuildImage' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':bootBuildImage' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
Building image 'docker.io/library/temp:latest'

 > Pulling builder image 'gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/builder:base-platform-api-0.3' ..................................................
 > Pulled builder image 'gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/builder@sha256:200fb7945ef0f4a3c79befb1262fd592f54ba7b7ffcc8a37716434dd11d0e5e9'
 > Pulling run image 'gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/run:base-cnb' ..................................................
 > Pulled run image 'gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/run@sha256:f7f27462fb513a70370322ada08440a642d24a700056d4c6b8cbb344610bf486'
 > Executing lifecycle version v0.7.5
 > Using build cache volume 'pack-cache-739c2c210811.build'

 > Running creator
    [creator]     ---> DETECTING
    [creator]     ======== Results ========
    [creator]     pass: paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica@2.7.1
    [creator]     skip: paketo-buildpacks/gradle@1.2.2
    [creator]     skip: paketo-buildpacks/maven@1.4.2
    [creator]     skip: paketo-buildpacks/sbt@1.2.2
    [creator]     pass: paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar@1.2.5
    [creator]     pass: paketo-buildpacks/apache-tomcat@1.1.5
    [creator]     pass: paketo-buildpacks/dist-zip@1.3.2
    [creator]     pass: paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot@1.5.5
    [creator]     skip: paketo-buildpacks/procfile@1.3.5
    [creator]     skip: paketo-buildpacks/azure-application-insights@1.2.1
    [creator]     skip: paketo-buildpacks/debug@1.2.5
    [creator]     skip: paketo-buildpacks/google-stackdriver@1.2.1
    [creator]     skip: paketo-buildpacks/jmx@1.1.5
    [creator]     skip: paketo-buildpacks/encrypt-at-rest@1.2.5
    [creator]     skip: paketo-buildpacks/image-labels@1.0.5
    [creator]     Resolving plan... (try #1)
    [creator]     fail: paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica@2.7.1 provides unused jdk
    [creator]     Resolving plan... (try #2)
    [creator]     skip: paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar@1.2.5 requires jre
    [creator]     skip: paketo-buildpacks/apache-tomcat@1.1.5 requires jre
    [creator]     skip: paketo-buildpacks/dist-zip@1.3.2 requires jre
    [creator]     fail: paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica@2.7.1 provides unused jdk
    [creator]     Resolving plan... (try #3)
    [creator]     5 of 15 buildpacks participating
    [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica 2.7.1
    [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar    1.2.5
    [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/apache-tomcat     1.1.5
    [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/dist-zip          1.3.2
    [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot       1.5.5
    [creator]     ---> ANALYZING
    [creator]     Analyzing image "c48997fb4f4f2e07e64033a33545298861d1f71f6a11a992bbb17cc84ecefee5"
    [creator]     ---> RESTORING
    [creator]     ---> BUILDING
    [creator]
    [creator]     Paketo BellSoft Liberica Buildpack 2.7.1
    [creator]         Set $BPL_JVM_HEAD_ROOM to configure the headroom in memory calculation. Default 0.
    [creator]         Set $BPL_JVM_LOADED_CLASS_COUNT to configure the number of loaded classes in memory calculation. Default 35% of classes.
    [creator]         Set $BPL_JVM_THREAD_COUNT to configure the number of threads in memory calculation. Default 250.
    [creator]         Set $BP_JVM_VERSION to configure the Java version. Default 11.*.
    [creator]       BellSoft Liberica JRE 8.0.252: Contributing to layer
    [creator]         Downloading from https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/8u252+9/bellsoft-jre8u252+9-linux-amd64.tar.gz
    [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
    [creator]     unable to get dependency jre
    [creator]     unable to download https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/8u252+9/bellsoft-jre8u252+9-linux-amd64.tar.gz
    [creator]     unable to request https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/8u252+9/bellsoft-jre8u252+9-linux-amd64.tar.gz
    [creator]     Get "https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/8u252+9/bellsoft-jre8u252+9-linux-amd64.tar.gz": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
    [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
```

Here is the log -> I'm wondering if there is a way to inject the SSL certs into the base container...

thanks

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried following environment variables?:

- DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY Enable secure HTTPS protocol when set to 1
  (optional)
- DOCKER_CERT_PATH Path to certificate and key files for
  HTTPS (required if DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1, ignored otherwise)

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#build-image

Comment: Unfortunately that appears to deal with the comms between Gradle and Docker -> not the engine itself ... but I'll give it a whirl and see what's up